# Exception in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, phalcon

I have following in my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And I need to add exciption for every `.php` file in base directory

for example: `domain.com/phpfile.php?value=22` should go out of .htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
#stop rewriting php files
RewriteRule \.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```